# Overriding .NET WebBrowsers WndProc

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, wndproc

For one of my projects, i'm overriding a AXShockwaveFlash control to disable right click and i can manage it using the following code;

```
public class FlashPlayer : AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash
{
    private const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;
    private const int WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A;
    private const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
    private const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;
    private const int WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0203; 
    private const int WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204;
    private const int WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205;                      

    public new event MouseEventHandler DoubleClick;

    public new event MouseEventHandler MouseDown;

    public new event MouseEventHandler MouseUp;

    public new event MouseEventHandler MouseMove;

    public FlashPlayer()
    {
        this.HandleCreated += FlashPlayer_HandleCreated; // listen for the HandleCreated event.
    }

    void FlashPlayer_HandleCreated(object sender, EventArgs e) // make required configuration changes.
    {
        this.AllowFullScreen = "true";
        this.AllowNetworking = "all";
        this.AllowScriptAccess = "always";
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) // Override's the WndProc and disables Flash activex's default right-click menu and if one exists shows the attached ContextMenuStrip.
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
                if (this.MouseDown != null) this.MouseDown(this, new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, 1, Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y, 0));
                break;
            case WM_LBUTTONUP:
                if (this.MouseUp != null) this.MouseUp(this, new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.None, 0, Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y, 0));
                break;
            case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
                if (this.MouseMove != null) this.MouseMove(this, new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.None, 0, Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y, 0));
                break;
            case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
                if (this.ContextMenuStrip != null) this.ContextMenuStrip.Show(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
                m.Result = IntPtr.Zero; // don't allow actual flash control process the message by flagging it as processed.
                return;
            case WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
                if (this.DoubleClick != null) this.DoubleClick(this, new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, 2, Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y, 0));
                m.Result = IntPtr.Zero; // don't allow actual flash control process the message by flagging it as processed.
                return;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m); // when we're done with processing the events, let the message pass to others also too.
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use the code for also a WebBrowser control, but my click events on WebBrowser's WndProc are not caught at all.

Any ideas?

**Update**: What i'm trying to do is disabling the right-click completely on web-browser, `IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled` does not work in my condition because a flash-component in web-browser still handles the right clicks and render it's own menu.

Comment: Yet another right-click disabling.. What for do you want to implement that? Don't limit user in his right to do what he wants

Comment: sorry, i'll not be discussing the UI decisions here. Basicly the idea is my own right-click menu where i can can provide features like borderless-forms, chat rooms and etc for the movie played.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your update, I guess that the problem is that the WebBrowser does not receive the messages because the messages are redirected to a Flash window. Making the flash player windowless (I think it's a wmode parameter) might work, otherwise you'll need to enumerate the child windows of the web browser to find the control, and then subclass it.